# Unable to Parse the Json file using Open Json in SQL

Tags: sql, json, parsing, open-json

I've a JSON file content and I want read the content using Open JSON and load it into the SQL.
need help in loading the content to SQl.

```json
{
    "Header": {
        "Time": "2023-11-22T01:39:22-08:00",
        "ReportName": "AgedReceivableDetail",
        "EndPeriod": "2023-09-30",
        "Currency": "USD",
        "Option": [
            {
                "Name": "report_date",
                "Value": "2023-09-30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "NoReportData",
                "Value": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Columns": {
        "Column": [
            {
                "ColTitle": "Date",
                "ColType": "tx_date"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Transaction Type",
                "ColType": "txn_type"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Num",
                "ColType": "doc_num"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Customer",
                "ColType": "cust_name"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Due Date",
                "ColType": "due_date"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Amount",
                "ColType": "subt_amount"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Open Balance",
                "ColType": "subt_open_bal"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Rows": {
        "Row": [
            {
                "Header": {
                    "ColData": [
                        {
                            "value": "Current"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Rows": {
                    "Row": [
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-08-31"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "60"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1016"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Kookies lts",
                                    "id": "16"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-30"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "75.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "75.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "92"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1028"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Freeman Twin Lane",
                                    "id": "9"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-10-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "81.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "81.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "75"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1027"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Bills Pvt",
                                    "id": "2"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-10-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "85.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "85.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-27"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "67"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1021"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Animal Inc Sanctuary",
                                    "id": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-10-27"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "459.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "459.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Summary": {
                    "ColData": [
                        {
                            "value": "Total for Current"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "1736.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "1631.00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Section"
            },
            {
                "Summary": {
                    "ColData": [
                        {
                            "value": "TOTAL"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "2279.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "2174.00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Section"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

used the below code to parse and but no luck.
please try to help me in processing this JSON file.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable
-- Create a temporary table to store the JSON data
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    [Key] NVARCHAR(255),
    [Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

-- Insert the JSON data into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('$', N'{
    "Header": {
        "Time": "2023-11-22T01:39:22-08:00",
        "ReportName": "ARDetail",
        "EndPeriod": "2023-09-30",
        "Currency": "USD",
        "Option": [
            {
                "Name": "report_date",
                "Value": "2023-09-30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "NoReportData",
                "Value": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Columns": {
        "Column": [
            {
                "ColTitle": "Date",
                "ColType": "tx_date"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Transaction Type",
                "ColType": "txn_type"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Num",
                "ColType": "doc_num"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Customer",
                "ColType": "cust_name"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Due Date",
                "ColType": "due_date"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Amount",
                "ColType": "subt_amount"
            },
            {
                "ColTitle": "Open Balance",
                "ColType": "subt_open_bal"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Rows": {
        "Row": [
            {
                "Header": {
                    "ColData": [
                        {
                            "value": "Current"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Rows": {
                    "Row": [
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-08-31"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "60"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1016"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Kookies lts",
                                    "id": "16"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-30"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "75.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "75.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "92"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1028"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Freeman Twin Lane",
                                    "id": "9"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-10-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "81.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "81.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "75"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1027"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Bills Pvt",
                                    "id": "2"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-10-01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "85.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "85.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                            "ColData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-09-27"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Invoice",
                                    "id": "67"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1021"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Animal Inc Sanctuary",
                                    "id": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2023-10-27"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "459.00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "459.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "Data"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Summary": {
                    "ColData": [
                        {
                            "value": "Total for Current"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "1736.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "1631.00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Section"
            },
            {
                "Summary": {
                    "ColData": [
                        {
                            "value": "TOTAL"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "2279.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "2174.00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Section"
            }
        ]
    }
}')


SELECT
    [Time]
    ,ReportName
    ,EndPeriod
    ,Currency
    ,[Option].Value AS ReportDate
    ,[Option].Value AS NoReportData
    ,ColumnData.ColTitle
    ,ColumnData.ColType
    ,RowData.type AS RowType

FROM
    #TempTable
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(#TempTable.[Value], '$.Header') WITH
    (
        Time NVARCHAR(25) '$.Time',
        ReportName NVARCHAR(255) '$.ReportName',
        EndPeriod NVARCHAR(25) '$.EndPeriod',
        Currency NVARCHAR(3) '$.Currency',
        [Option] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Option' AS JSON
    ) AS Header
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(Header.[Option]) WITH
    (
        Name NVARCHAR(255) '$.Name',
        Value NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Value'
    ) AS [Option]
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(#TempTable.[Value], '$.Columns') WITH
    (
        ColumnData NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Columns.Column' AS JSON
    ) AS Columns
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(ColumnData) WITH
    (
        ColTitle NVARCHAR(255) '$.ColTitle',
        ColType NVARCHAR(50) '$.ColType'
    ) AS ColumnData
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(#TempTable.[Value], '$.Rows') WITH
    (
        RowData NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Rows.Row' AS JSON
    ) AS Rows
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(RowData) WITH
    (
        type NVARCHAR(50) '$.type',
        Header NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Header' AS JSON,
        Rows NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Rows.Row' AS JSON,
        Summary NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Summary' AS JSON
    ) AS RowData

-- Drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) it with the DBMS implementation (e.g. [tag:mysql], [tag:postgresql], [tag:oracle], MS [tag:sql-server], IBM [tag:db2], etc.) being used, as suggested in the [tag info for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).